# Android Studio Firebase doesn't recognize the registered account after wiping user data from android emulator

Tags: java, android, firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication

I was going to my AVD manager to see how much my emulator storage is taking and I got surprised that it almost got 20GB of my PC so I wiped out the emulators data but when I login with my firebase app, it doesn't recognize the account anymore and gives an error of firebase "no user record corresponding to this identifyer error or Firebaseauthinvaliduserexception" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1NRz.png)  even though the account still exists in firebase [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc2wD.png)

edit: maybe imgur sucks idk how to display it and idk if it will be displayed the firebase error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1NRz.png)

So if ever the user wipes the data of my app, how will I fix this kind of error

Code here for login activity:

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button login, register;
EditText provided_email, provided_pass;
String emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser mUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    register = findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    provided_email = findViewById(R.id.provided_email);
    provided_pass = findViewById(R.id.provided_pass);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { Register(); }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { LogAuth(); }
    });
}
//prevents current activity from going further back
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Reached the end of going back using back button",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
public void Register(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

//login authorize, requires firebase auth
private void LogAuth(){
    //trim() to make sure it turns to string: advisable and just followed
    String email = provided_email.getText().toString();
    String pass = provided_pass.getText().toString();

    if(!email.matches(emailPattern)) {
        provided_email.setError("Enter Correct Email");
    }
    else if(pass.isEmpty() || pass.length()<6) {
        provided_pass.setError("Enter a password no less than 6 letters long");
    }
    else{
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while login is processing...");
        progressDialog.setTitle("Login");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        //tell authentication to sign in with email and password
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete( Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    sendUserToNextActivity();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void sendUserToNextActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

XML code used:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/background_color"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_brand"
    android:layout_width="261dp"
    android:layout_height="93dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    android:text="Job Tinder"
    android:textColor="@color/tealgreen"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/white"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/provided_email"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:ems="50"
    android:background="@drawable/background_textview"
    android:hint="Ex: name@gmail.com"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_brand" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/provided_pass"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="50"
    android:background="@drawable/background_textview"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/provided_email" />

<android.widget.Button
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/tealgreen"
    android:text="Login"
    android:background="@drawable/button_design"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/provided_pass" />

<android.widget.Button
    android:id="@+id/register_button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_design"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_button" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hoping there could be a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "I wiped out the emulators data"?

Comment: @AlexMamo "In the AVD manager in android studio, there is an option to wipe user data for the selected android emulator. It's space was 20GB long so I decided to "wipe user data" it to free up space that's when firebase login could no longer recognize the account even though the account is still in authentication at firebase google"